# YouTube Tutorial Can't select second Item in Listview (Invalid argument)

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2008

I am trying to follow along and complete this address book tutorial on YouTube [Address Book Tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0ZoDmeAZAD8&feature=relmfu)

But I have ran into a snag that I don't understand. Following along I cannot find the difference in code. So I am thinking it must be a property setting that I am missing. When I test populate the list I can select the first item. But when I select the second item the debugger kicks out an error

> invalid argument=value of '0' is not valid for 'index'

Can someone tell me why this error is thrown? Listening to the video it sounds like the 0 in the code is to tell the list that you can only select one item at a time. Unfortunately I haven't been able to figure out why his code works and mine does not.

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    person p = new person(); // creates new string array
    p.Name = textBox1.Text;  // name    
    p.StreetAddress= textBox3.Text; // address
    p.Email = textBox2.Text;  // email
    p.Birthday = dateTimePicker1.Value;  //birthday
    p.AdditionalNotes = textBox4.Text;  // any notes
    people.Add(p); // tells the the above data to be added to the people list.
    listView1.Items.Add(p.Name); // makes its show on the listview of the main box.
    textBox1.Text = "";
    textBox2.Text = "";
    textBox3.Text = "";
    textBox4.Text = "";
    dateTimePicker1.Value = DateTime.Now;

}

private void listView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    textBox1.Text = people[listView1.SelectedItems[0].Index].Name; //Debugger points error here.
    textBox2.Text = people[listView1.SelectedItems[0].Index].Email;
    textBox3.Text = people[listView1.SelectedItems[0].Index].StreetAddress;
    textBox4.Text = people[listView1.SelectedItems[0].Index].AdditionalNotes;
    dateTimePicker1.Value = people[listView1.SelectedItems[0].Index].Birthday;
}


class person
{
    public string Name
    {
        get;
        set;
    }  ...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to speak with the program creator. The solution is to check and handle no selection. So Adding an If statement solved the Issue.

```
private void listView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (listView1.SelectedItems.Count == 0) return;  // This line added will solve the problem
    textBox1.Text = people[listView1.SelectedItems[0].Index].Name; 
    textBox2.Text = people[listView1.SelectedItems[0].Index].Email;
    textBox3.Text = people[listView1.SelectedItems[0].Index].StreetAddress;
    textBox4.Text = people[listView1.SelectedItems[0].Index].AdditionalNotes;
    dateTimePicker1.Value = people[listView1.SelectedItems[0].Index].Birthday;
}
```